# No module named 'tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops'

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried to run jupyter from Ubuntu inside windows. After loaded a .ipynb file, `model.fit(...` gave me
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops`. I tried to uninstall and reinstall tensorflow from Ubuntu inside windows with version 2.3.1/1.14, still the same error message.

Even I uninstalled tensorflow, `print(tf.__version__)` still printed `2.3.1`. I am not sure if it is related to the interaction between Windows and Ubuntu subsystem. I tried to logout and login ubuntu subsystem to update my .bashrc file, still the same thing.

Hence, I would like to know what is the solution :(

Answer (score 2):

Had the same Problem with Tensorflow 2.3.0

Seems like they moved the Module to the newest Version and that's why this error suddenly comes up.
(Source: https://github.com/google/trax/issues/747)

Upgrading to the newest Tensorflow Version should fix it.