# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to start learning some Machine Learning and am trying to import Tensorflow but am getting a ModuleNotFoundError:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops'
```

The code currently just tries to import packages:

```
import os
import sys
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras import LSTM
```

The full traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 

 File "C:\Users\stacey\Documents\Atela\MachineLearning\NeuralNetworks\NeuralNetwork1.0.py", line 17, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras import LSTM

  File "C:\Users\stacey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util

  File "C:\Users\stacey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import distribute

  File "C:\Users\stacey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.distribute.experimental import collective_all_reduce_strategy

  File "C:\Users\stacey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\experimental\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.distribute import tpu_strategy

  File "C:\Users\stacey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\tpu_strategy.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.compiler.xla.experimental.xla_sharding import xla_sharding

  File "C:\Users\stacey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\compiler\xla\experimental\xla_sharding\xla_sharding.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.compiler.tf2xla.python import xla as tf2xla

  File "C:\Users\stacey\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\compiler\tf2xla\python\xla.py", line 43, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops import np_utils

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops'
```

Python version: 3.6
Tensorflow version: 2.6.2

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a `tensorflow.keras.LSTM`. Maybe you're looking for [`tensorflow.keras.layers.LSTM`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM) ?

**Update:**

The issue was solved by [upgrading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66203280/14774959) to the latest versions both tensorflow (2.9.1) and python (3.9). [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source?hl=en#tested_build_configurations) can be found a version compatibility table.

Comment: I tried from keras.layers import LSTM but got the same error

Comment: Does this help ? Maybe you just have to upgrade tensorflow version https://stackoverflow.com/a/66203280/14774959

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled before posting the question - how do I make sure I have the latest version?

Comment: I think you could do `pip install tensorflow --upgrade`, or `pip install tensorflow==2.9.1` (2.9.1 is the latest currently available). Also if you are using a gpu you have to install `tensorflow-gpu` instead. However, I see that you are using python 3.6, so maybe the newer tensorflow versions aren't compatible with it.

Comment: Yes, it looks like that with python 3.6, the maximum version of tensorflow that you can get is 2.6. If it's not a problem for you, you should consider also upgrading python https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source?hl=en#tested_build_configurations

Comment: Thanks @ClaudiaR - ended up removing python and all the packages and reinstalling everything with up to date versions which sorted the issue out