# Cannot import name 'np_config' from 'tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops'

Tags: tensorflow

I tried importing the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops import np_config
```

I got the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'np_config' from 'tensorflow.python.ops.numpy_ops' (C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\numpy_ops\__init__.py)
```

I checked versions of tensorflow and keras:

```
import tensorflow
print(tf.__version__)
import keras
print(keras.__version__)
```

Output:

```
2.4.0
2.4.0
```

**Edit**: I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65103561/no-module-named-tensorflow-python-ops-numpy-ops) but still not working.

Comment: Why do you want to import this from private API? It was introduced in TF 2.5

Comment: @Frightera. Solved it. Thanks. What is the keras version compatible with tensorflow 2.5 please?

Comment: Hi @Avv, For tensorflow 2.5.0  you can use  keras 2.5.0 version. If you install tensorflow using pip the compatible version of keras will be automatically downloaded. Thank You.